# Adding timestamp automatically through AWS Appsync resolver with Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I tried to add timestamp automatically when I create some post.
But it is not working the example of appsync resolver-context-reference.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#time-helpers-in-util-time

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key": {
        "id" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId())
    },

    #set( $myfoo = $util.dynamodb.toMapValues($ctx.args) )
    #set( $myFoo.version = $util.dynamodb.toNumber(1) )
    #set( $myFoo.timestamp = $util.time.nowISO8601() )

    "attributeValues" : $util.toJson($myFoo)
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the timestamp while writing to the DB or upon returning the values? Looks likes the latter.

Comment: @Vladimir It is for while writing the DB.

Comment: Got it. See my answer then.

Answer (score 7):

This is a working example of what you're looking to do (taken from my AppSync API resolver). Note the "messageId" and "createdDate" attributes. That's how you can add a date while writing to DDB.

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "eventId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.eventId),
    "messageId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson("$util.time.nowISO8601()$util.autoId()"),
  },
  "attributeValues": {
    "message": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.message),
    "createdDate": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.time.nowISO8601())
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it work correctly as `"$util.time.nowISO8601()$util.autoId()"`?

Comment: Yes. You can use additional values for sorting and range purposes as well. Up to you. Here's a good guide to follow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html

Comment: I was strugging on how to pass the current itmestamp to dynamodb to fetch a result and found this post and used this --> $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.time.nowISO8601()) and it worked like charm. Thanks for the code snippet. You saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

Change your resolver to the following

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key": {
        "id" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId())
    },

    #set( $myFoo = $util.dynamodb.toMapValues($ctx.args) )
    #set( $myFoo.version = $util.dynamodb.toNumber(1) )
    #set( $myFoo.timestamp = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.time.nowISO8601()) )

    "attributeValues" : $util.toJson($myFoo)
}
```

Also note the call to `$util.time.nowISO8601()` is now wrapped with `$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB()`

Answer (score 1):

For dynamoDB, `String` should change to dynamodb type through `$util`. Thus, it would be work after changing time string to dynamoDB type.

```
#set( $myFoo.timestamp = $util.time.nowISO8601() )
=>  
#set( $myFoo.timestamp = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.time.nowISO8601())
```